# HtmlUnit + reCaptcha

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am trying to spider reCaptcha service from

The main site is: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

I am using version 2.30.

this is what I tried so far:

```
  try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.getDefault())) {

                    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

final HtmlPage home = webClient.getPage("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo");

webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20000);

final HtmlSpan reCaptchaAnchor = home.getForms().get(0).getFirstByXPath(".//span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']");

if (reCaptchaAnchor == null) {
                        throw new NullPointerException("Captcha not found");
}
```

Comment: The span you are looking for is inside a frame, start with the page, find the frame go to the inner document and then you can find the form.

Comment: mmm I already try that. 

home.getFrames() -> size = 0

Comment: Did you solve the problem?